# Creating Multiple Instances of a Variable C++

Tags: c++, input

I'm attempting to make a tool for this Minecraft Chat Client where you can log into servers using batch files instead of launching the actual minecraft client.  I'm attempting to make a tool that you could put your account details in and have it output the rest of the text needed in the batch file along with the server ip that you want.  Also I'm sorry if what I'm asking for in the title isn't what I should be doing. I just needed something to put there to give someone a rough idea before looking at the thread of what I need help with.

Here is a picture I made in paint showing the basic layout. I'm not asking for help with the gui, I just made it to help visual people and just in case I'm making absolutely no sense.:

[image]

Minecraft Chat Client

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1314800-winmaclinux-minecraft-console-client-175/

All I need help with is how to input lets say 25 minecraft accounts into that "Input Alts" box and have the program recognize how many alts are there and then simply output them in the format I have in the picture.  I know how to do everything else using basic cin or cout.  I was wondering if creating an array would be a good solution but I just don't know how to make the program recognize each account as its own separate identity.  If it would be easier to just have a separate input where you could manually put the number of alts you are trying to output then I don't mind doing it that way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I figured out how to do it with one account at a time but it takes too long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//Minecraft Account Details
string account = " ";
//Minecraft Server IP
string serverIPAddress = "";

int main()
{
cout << "Please Enter your email and password in the following format\n";

cout << "example@email.com password1\n";

// Lets say we input "example@email.com password1".
getline(cin, account);

// Lets just use "minecraftserver.com".
cout << "Please Enter The server IP";
getline(cin, serverIPAddress);

cout << "Minecraft.exe " << account << " " << serverIPAddress << endl;
//Output: Minecraft.exe example@email.com password1 minecraftserver.com

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jagannath it's very unclear. For example the storyboard screen has a GUI whereas the sample code is a console program, and the act of grabbing lines out of a GUI -- which is central to the problem -- is quite different to reading a console

Comment: @Westfall is there supposed to be separate server IP per user/pass, or  one server IP for all?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to read the user/pass details and then store them in a container. The code in `main()` could look like:

```
// input stuff
std::vector<std::string> accounts;
std::cout << "Please Enter The username and passwords\n";

for ( std::string temp; std::getline(std::cin, temp); )
    accounts.push_back(temp);

std::string server_ip;
std::cout << "Please Enter The server IP\n";
std::getline(server_ip);

// output stuff
for ( auto&& acc : accounts )
    std::cout << acc << ' ' << server_ip << '\n';
```